# Change control management for Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

Is there a change control management for Couchbase? Something like Liquibase for SQL or Mongeez for MongoDB?
My scenario is that we store application configuration in Couchbase, and we need a way to update this configuration automatically for dev/sand/prod environments.

Comment: Is there any application like liquibase for couchbase ?

Comment: I ended up writing my own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Couchmove](https://github.com/differentway/couchmove), which is a java migration tools that works like Flyway DB.